# Android App gets killed by OS in certain devices

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I have an android app which gets data from Bluetooth and plots this data over osmroid Mapview continuously but after certain time the OS kills this app but this happens only in certain device.

This kill does not occur in HTC,samsung devices.

Please help me to find out why it is happening in certain devices. Also please provide me with a solution for this problem.

```
04-17 13:16:06.594 12536-12536/? I/ContextImpl: startServiceCommon service:Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService (has extras) }, user:UserHandle{0}
04-17 13:16:06.603 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = turn_silent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.603 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = callsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.603 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = alarmsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.603 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = musicsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.603 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = mediasilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.603 1016-1016/? I/fanzhuan: onSensorChanged front----> 0.104  0.005  9.846
04-17 13:16:06.612 1016-1026/? I/ActivityManager: startServiceLocked service:Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService (has extras) }
04-17 13:16:06.644 1016-1772/? D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=249043682, flags=0x1, tag="wake:com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService", ws=null, uid=10011, pid=12536
04-17 13:16:06.652 1016-1772/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock mPackageName:android, mTag:WindowManager
04-17 13:16:06.652 1016-1772/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = *net_scheduler*
04-17 13:16:06.652 1016-1772/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = Checkin Service
04-17 13:16:06.652 1016-1772/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock mPackageName:android, mTag:*alarm*
04-17 13:16:06.652 1016-1772/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = *net_scheduler*
04-17 13:16:06.653 1016-1772/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = Checkin Service
04-17 13:16:06.653 1016-1772/? D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x23
04-17 13:16:06.654 1016-1772/? D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=8355076 (in 1778733 ms)
04-17 13:16:06.657 1016-1772/? D/DisplayPowerController: requestPowerState: policy=BRIGHT, useProximitySensor=false, screenBrightness=240, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.0, brightnessSetByUser=true, useAutoBrightness=false, blockScreenOn=false, lowPowerMode=false, boostScreenBrightness=false, dozeScreenBrightness=-1, dozeScreenState=UNKNOWN, waitForNegativeProximity=false
04-17 13:16:06.658 1016-1772/? I/PowerManagerService: setBrightness mButtonLight 0.
04-17 13:16:06.658 1016-1772/? D/PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x23, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
04-17 13:16:06.659 1016-1772/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="wake:com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10011, ownerPid=12536, workSource=null
04-17 13:16:06.663 1016-1772/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 10011 package com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:06.679 12536-12536/? D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { flg=0x114 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogServiceReceiver (has extras) } packageName=com.google.android.gms resultCode=0 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
04-17 13:16:06.686 1016-1016/? D/AlarmManager: onSendFinished begin
04-17 13:16:06.691 1016-1016/? D/PowerManagerService: releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=141471969 [*alarm*], flags=0x0, total_time=2031ms
04-17 13:16:06.694 12536-12536/? D/ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service: CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@fff5a58 className=com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService packageName=com.google.android.gms intent=null}
04-17 13:16:06.696 12536-12536/? D/ActivityThread: SVC-CREATE_SERVICE handled : 0 / CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@fff5a58 className=com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService packageName=com.google.android.gms intent=null}
04-17 13:16:06.696 12536-12536/? D/ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.google.android.gms.checkin.EventLogService@55077b1, flags=0, startId=1
04-17 13:16:06.721 1016-1016/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="*alarm*", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1016, workSource=WorkSource{10011}
04-17 13:16:06.722 1016-1016/? D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x23
04-17 13:16:06.722 1016-1016/? D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=8355076 (in 1778665 ms)
04-17 13:16:06.722 1016-1016/? D/DisplayPowerController: requestPowerState: policy=BRIGHT, useProximitySensor=false, screenBrightness=240, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.0, brightnessSetByUser=true, useAutoBrightness=false, blockScreenOn=false, lowPowerMode=false, boostScreenBrightness=false, dozeScreenBrightness=-1, dozeScreenState=UNKNOWN, waitForNegativeProximity=false
04-17 13:16:06.722 1016-1016/? I/PowerManagerService: setBrightness mButtonLight 0.
04-17 13:16:06.722 1016-1016/? D/PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x23, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
04-17 13:16:06.727 1016-10160/? D/PowerManagerService: acquireWakeLockInternal: lock=117472883, flags=0x1, tag="Event Log Service", ws=WorkSource{10011 com.google.android.gms}, uid=10011, pid=12536
04-17 13:16:06.727 1016-10160/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock mPackageName:android, mTag:WindowManager
04-17 13:16:06.727 1016-10160/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = *net_scheduler*
04-17 13:16:06.727 1016-10160/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = Checkin Service
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock mPackageName:com.google.android.gms, mTag:wake:com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = *net_scheduler*
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? I/muxinwu: PowerManagerService agoldReleaseWakelock package_name = com.google.android.gms, tag_name = Checkin Service
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x23
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=8355076 (in 1778659 ms)
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? D/DisplayPowerController: requestPowerState: policy=BRIGHT, useProximitySensor=false, screenBrightness=240, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.0, brightnessSetByUser=true, useAutoBrightness=false, blockScreenOn=false, lowPowerMode=false, boostScreenBrightness=false, dozeScreenBrightness=-1, dozeScreenState=UNKNOWN, waitForNegativeProximity=false
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? I/PowerManagerService: setBrightness mButtonLight 0.
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? D/PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x23, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
04-17 13:16:06.728 1016-10160/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="Event Log Service", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10011, ownerPid=12536, workSource=WorkSource{10011 com.google.android.gms}
04-17 13:16:06.730 1016-1144/? D/PowerManagerService: releaseWakeLockInternal: lock=249043682 [wake:com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService], flags=0x0, total_time=77ms
04-17 13:16:06.730 1016-1144/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="wake:com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService", packageName=com.google.android.gms, ownerUid=10011, ownerPid=12536, workSource=null
04-17 13:16:06.730 1016-1144/? D/PowerManagerService: updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x23
04-17 13:16:06.730 1016-1144/? D/PowerManagerService: updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, nextTimeout=8355076 (in 1778657 ms)
04-17 13:16:06.730 1016-1144/? D/DisplayPowerController: requestPowerState: policy=BRIGHT, useProximitySensor=false, screenBrightness=240, screenAutoBrightnessAdjustment=0.0, brightnessSetByUser=true, useAutoBrightness=false, blockScreenOn=false, lowPowerMode=false, boostScreenBrightness=false, dozeScreenBrightness=-1, dozeScreenState=UNKNOWN, waitForNegativeProximity=false
04-17 13:16:06.730 1016-1144/? I/PowerManagerService: setBrightness mButtonLight 0.
04-17 13:16:06.730 1016-1144/? D/PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, policy=3, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x23, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true, mScreenBrightnessBoostInProgress=false
04-17 13:16:06.755 12536-12536/? D/ActivityThread: SVC-SERVICE_ARGS handled : 0 / ServiceArgsData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@fff5a58 startId=1 args=Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.checkin.EventLogService (has extras) }}
04-17 13:16:06.803 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = turn_silent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.803 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = callsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.803 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = alarmsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.803 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = musicsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.803 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = mediasilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:06.804 1016-1016/? I/fanzhuan: onSensorChanged front----> 0.089  0.005  9.853
04-17 13:16:06.833 12536-12583/? I/ContextImpl: bindServiceCommon service:Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.usagereporting.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
04-17 13:16:06.835 1016-1716/? I/ActivityManager: bindServiceLocked service:Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.usagereporting.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
04-17 13:16:06.845 1016-1716/? W/PackageManager: checkUidPermission(): android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE of 10011 is denied.
04-17 13:16:06.857 1016-1716/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 12584:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a11 for service com.google.android.gms/.usagereporting.service.UsageReportingService
04-17 13:16:06.857 1016-1716/? I/ActivityManager: [Background Service Priority Adjustment] Process.setProcessGroup to Process.THREAD_GROUP_BG_NONINTERACTIVE, app.pid: 12584
04-17 13:16:07.003 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = turn_silent , value = null
04-17 13:16:07.003 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = callsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:07.003 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = alarmsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:07.003 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = musicsilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:07.003 1016-1016/? D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = mediasilent , value = null
04-17 13:16:07.003 1016-1016/? I/fanzhuan: onSensorChanged front----> 0.05  0.032  9.864
04-17 13:16:07.030 12584-12591/? I/System: FinalizerDaemon: finalize objects = 1
04-17 13:16:07.041 12584-12584/? I/LoadedApk: No resource references to update in package FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
04-17 13:16:07.041 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.050 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.051 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.053 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.056 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.058 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.059 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.060 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms
04-17 13:16:07.062 12584-12584/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.google.android.gms

    tyManager: SVC-mBroadcastQueues: com.android.server.am.BroadcastQueue@4d6409c
04-17 13:16:04.882 1016-1016/? E/AppWidgetServiceImpl: Error clearing service interface
                                                       android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                           at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                           at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:511)
                                                           at com.android.internal.widget.IRemoteViewsAdapterConnection$Stub$Proxy.onServiceDisconnected(IRemoteViewsAdapterConnection.java:95)
                                                           at com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl$ServiceConnectionProxy.disconnect(AppWidgetServiceImpl.java:3546)
                                                           at com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl$ServiceConnectionProxy.onServiceDisconnected(AppWidgetServiceImpl.java:3541)
                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doDeath(LoadedApk.java:1269)
                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1283)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                           at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:371)
                                                           at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:234)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:749)
04-17 13:16:04.882 1605-1697/? D/ForegroundUtils: Process died; UID 10041 PID 12520
04-17 13:16:04.883 1605-1697/? D/ForegroundUtils:   foregroundPids.delete(pid) 12520
04-17 13:16:04.883 1605-1697/? D/ForegroundUtils:   mForegroundUidPids.remove  uid:10041
04-17 13:16:04.883 1605-1697/? D/ForegroundUtils:   handleUidToBackground  uid:10041
04-17 13:16:04.883 1605-1697/? D/ForegroundUtils: Foreground changed, PID: 12520 UID: 10041 foreground: false
04-17 13:16:04.883 1605-1697/? D/ForegroundUtils: Foreground UID/PID combinations:
04-17 13:16:04.883 1605-1697/? D/ForegroundUtils: UID: 10188 PID: 7988
```

Comment: App killed ? Do you mean os kills your service which running in background ?

Comment: Faced the same issues in My MI Devices

Comment: @ADM Yes i guess,but it is not a crash.

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM Also,this happens in device called blackview

Comment: @RShenoy Based on this https://www.gizmochina.com/2014/12/14/blackview-ultra-ios-like-ui/  BlackView have IOS like Interface in Upon Android Core So it has  customized Android OS and This is the reason for Killing  Unwanted Services in Background

Comment: @RAJESHKUMARARUMUGAM Unwanted Services like? My app is running continously,how to avoid this kill?

Answer (score 1):

In kitkat the Os Kills a sticky service just when you kill it from recent app.So this is the OS specific issue i have faced too. I have also tried to restart the Service onTaskRemoved(). But seems no luck with Kitkat (Lenovo Device).

```
  @Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.e("Task","Removed");
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);

}
```

Although its works in other devices. So i finally end up with AlarmManager to check the Service is running or not at some time interval.
But before you use this Read the Android M and Android N Specification about Battery optimization and Doze mode [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html).

Comment: My testing on KitKat showed that a `START_STICKY` service will be automatically restarted several seconds after its activity is swiped from recents.

Comment: Yeah thats what i am saying but not in all device I have faced issues in a lenovo A series device. Also see the documentation for Android N . you will get amazed.

Comment: @ADM i am using Android M will this work for the same,Would like to have some more info about Battery optimization in Android M.